# How to access Redis on the server remotely?

Tags: database, redis, remote-access

I have a server that the Redis is installed on. We use it as a project's queue (and sometimes for caching).

Now I need to access it and its data from my local computer.

- Tried `redis-server` to make it accessible remotely, but it throwed

> Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use

- Tried `redis-server --port 6380` to serve it on another port, it server well, but I wasn't able to access it's data from my local computer, it throwed:

> (error) DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is enabled, no bind address was specified, no authentication password is requested to clients. In this mode connections are only accepted from the loopback interface. If you want to connect from external computers to Redis you may adopt one of the following solutions: 1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET protected-mode no' from the loopback interface by connecting to Redis from the same host the server is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE to make this change permanent. 2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode option to 'no', and then restarting the server. 3) If you started the server manually just for testing, restart it with the '--protected-mode no' option. 4) Setup a bind address or an authentication password. NOTE: You only need to do one of the above things in order for the server to start accepting connections from the outside.

- Tried `redis-server --port 6380 --protected-mode no`, now, I can access the Redis from my local computer, but when I run `keys *` query, it returns an empty array. While I need to access the data. Noted that, I can insert into the Redis and access what I've myself inserted, but not the real data that is currently exist on the Redis server.

How can I access the Redis data from my local computer?

Comment: Have you opened the port of your server on which redis is listening? And while you are connecting from redis-cli on you local pc, did you pass the server IP ?

Comment: Yes @ManaswitaMaiti I'm trying to access the Redis remotely this way: `redis-cli -h 185.x.x.x -p 6380`

Comment: Is the port 6380 open ? Inbound and outbound rules ?

Comment: @ManaswitaMaiti Are you talking about ufw? It's disabled on the server

Comment: Yes... ufw. Try enabling it and addthe inbound and outbound ports. Then also check with the VPS provider if there are any other settings to open a port. For eg. When I used AWS, I had to set rules on both ufw and AWS settings.